# Firebird update within reader

Tags: c#, firebird

Using Firebird 2.5 and .net engine.

I have following issue:

```
FbCommand cmd = new FBcommand(...select * from table ...);
FbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
... 

update table set ...

....
}
```

I'm updating some records within reader.
Let say, that in `select * from table` I've got 5 records. In while loop in first step I update second and third record. In second step I should get updated second row.

The problem is, if my database is connected as embedded, then these updates are visible. But, if I connect as ServerType = Default, then I see all rows without updates.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and describe in more detail what the problem is. There shouldn't be a differences between Firebird Embedded and normal Firebird Server itself. However, the implementation between those two are different in the Firebird .net provider (one uses a native component, while the other is implemented purely in C#), so possibly you have hit a bug there.

Comment: something about transactions? or about multiple connections in a auto-created pool (thus, about transactions in the end, instead of doing the changesin one connection? Connect to standalone (not embedded) Firebird server and monitor MON$ATTACHMENTS system table, will you see your app making more connections than it needs?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tryed to update to newest .net engine, but the problem persist. I have refractored my code now to two seperate connections, one for update, another for the loop. I solved my problem by now. But it seems there is something about transaction and connections going on. I'll dig into monitoring MON$ATTACHMENTS.

Comment: if your Firebird is 2.5 or newer you can also try TraceAPI in IBExpert or in http://FBProfiler.sf.net or any other ocmpatible tool.